# This was a problem I encountered while trying to solve a hacker rank warmup excercise

Tags: python

Hi i am really new to programming and stack as well, i am practicing python on hackerrank and this was the second question on the warmup page:

In this challenge, you are required to calculate and print the sum of the elements in an array, keeping in mind that some of those integers may be quite large.(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/a-very-big-sum/problem)

Given sample input:
Sample Input

1. 5
2. 1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005

Required output:

1. 5000000015

so eventually i thought that the first line of input would be the number of items in the list after the first index i.e something like arry = [5,1000000001,1000000002,1000000003,1000000004,1000000005]
and we have to calculate the sum of items that comes after the first index.
i couldn't figure out the logic for the same and looked for answers online and found out that others have just calculated the sum of the given input array or list and returned, nothing else, i did the same and it worked.

now my question is what is the first input for?
and have i read the question wrong, i m just frustrated that i am not getting the question in the first attempt.

This Code Worked:

```
def aVeryBigSum(ar):
    total = sum(ar)
    return total
```

Comment: Not every programming language makes life as easy as Python ...

Comment: so you mean to say the first input might be used by other coders using a different language

Comment: The examples on Hackerrang are mostly overspecified - they almost alwys provide a number of parameters forllowed by  a list with as many params as just mentioned. In python you can ignore the first param (you need to input() it and forget about it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem text says:

> The first line of the input consists of an integer n.
> The next line contains n space-separated integers contained in the array.

Which means that the first line should tell you how many space separated integers you need to read from the second line.